# How to load custom db adapter ? so that its ready when `database.yml` is evaluated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

In rails 4, I am trying to write my own database adapter, however, it seems that `database.yml` is evaluated before loading my adapter, leading into error:

```
Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/proxy_mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile.
```

My customer adapter is located at `lib/active_record/connection_handling/proxy_mysql2_adapter.rb`
, my attempt to loaded it at `config/application.rb` using `config.eager_load_paths` is not working, as it's loaded not before `config/database.yml` evaluation.

How would I load my db adapter? so that its ready when `database.yml` is evaluated?

Above is full error:

```
App 25085 output: Error: The application encountered the following error: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/proxy_mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:175:in `spec'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-import-0.13.0/lib/activerecord-import.rb:7:in `establish_connection_with_activerecord_import'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:28:in `block in on_load'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `each'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:27:in `on_load'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.6/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:116:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
App 25085 output:     /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/releases/20200310141409/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
App 25085 output:     config.ru:3:in `require'
App 25085 output:     config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
App 25085 output:     /var/www/backend/shared/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rack-1.6.13/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
App 25085 output:     config.ru:1:in `new'
App 25085 output:     config.ru:1:in `<main>'
App 25085 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `eval'
App 25085 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:101:in `preload_app'
App 25085 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:189:in `block in <module:App>'
App 25085 output:     /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:380:in `run_block_and_record_step_progress'
App 25085 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:188:in `<module:App>'
App 25085 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
App 25085 output:     /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
[ E 2020-03-10 15:22:10.0768 25063/Tf age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /var/www/backend/current: The application encountered the following error: Could not load 'active_record/connection_adapters/proxy_mysql2_adapter'. Make sure that the adapter in config/database.yml is valid. If you use an adapter other than 'mysql', 'mysql2', 'postgresql' or 'sqlite3' add the necessary adapter gem to the Gemfile. (LoadError)
  Error ID: 91fbd9ce
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-qdkLuQ.html
```

**EDIT2**

I tried to place it into initializers folder, but I got the same result, full adapter can be found here: https://gist.github.com/arthurchui/f4d1d74d5e91f5307b5c6c78bdfde365

Comment: I would just [create a gem](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwij_b-trZDoAhWyw4sKHZuiBy8QFjABegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fbundler.io%2Fguides%2Fcreating_gem.html&usg=AOvVaw2aGTSKIKIHuL63lNAdnMlj) so that its loaded when rails requires the application gems.

Comment: Otherwise right after `Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)` in `config/application.rb` is probably a good place to require your code. At that point the dependencies are loaded but the app is not yet initialized. https://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails only needs that file to be on load path, you can place it in one of directories that are in `$LOAD_PATH` after bundler is initialized, but before app is loaded, so `<rails_root>/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/proxy_mysql2_adapter.rb` is suitable.

Make sure it does not raise `LoadError` or `Gem::LoadError` upon load - if your adapter fails to require some other dependency, rails will think that it cannot find the adapter or its gem.

Comment: Thanks @Vasfed, its turns out I had an error in the path at which I stored `proxy_mysql2_adapter.rb` however, I had `uninitialized constant` error which you can see here https://gist.github.com/arthurchui/f4d1d74d5e91f5307b5c6c78bdfde365#gistcomment-3207887 if you are interested